# Remove columns from a CSV using Batch Command

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to create a batch file to delete the first two columns from a csv file

I already tried some codes that I found here on the stack, but they didn't work as I wanted

my input data is like this

```
Cenário;Tipo de Movimento;Conta;Centro de Custo;Jan;Fev;Mar;Abr;Mai;Jun;Jul;Ago;Set;Out;Nov;Dez;Total
Orçamento;Final;1102345;C01;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;12000
Orçamento;Final;1102346;C01;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;24000
Orçamento;Final;1102347;C05;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;36000
```

the Output must be like this

```
Conta;Centro de Custo;Jan;Fev;Mar;Abr;Mai;Jun;Jul;Ago;Set;Out;Nov;Dez;Total
1102345;C01;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;1000;12000
1102346;C01;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;2000;24000
1102347;C05;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;3000;36000
```

The codes i already tried

CODE 1

```
@echo off 
:main
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (ORIGINAL.csv) do (
call :sub1 %%a
)
goto :eof
:sub1
for /f "tokens=3* delims=;" %%w in ('type %1') do (
echo.%%w, %%x, %%y, %%z, %%aa, %%ab, %%ac, %%ad, %%ae, %%af, %%ag, %%ah, %%ai
) >> MOD.csv
goto :eof
```

OUTPUT 1 - `Don't give me anything`

CODE 2

```
@Echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%A in (ORIGINAL.csv) do Call :sub1 %%A
) > MOD.csv
goto :Eof
:sub1
Echo(%3',%4,%5,%6,%7,%8,%9,%10,%11,%12,%13,%14,%15
```

OUTPUT 2

```
de',Movimento,Conta,Centro,de,Custo,Jan,Cenário0,Cenário1,Cenário2,Cenário3,Cenário4,Cenário5
1102345',C01,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,Orçamento0,Orçamento1,Orçamento2,Orçamento3,Orçamento4,Orçamento5
1102346',C01,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,Orçamento0,Orçamento1,Orçamento2,Orçamento3,Orçamento4,Orçamento5
1102347',C05,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,Orçamento0,Orçamento1,Orçamento2,Orçamento3,Orçamento4,Orçamento5
```

CODE 3

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%x in (ORIGINAL.csv) do (
 set "line=%%x"
 for /F "tokens=3-15* delims=;" %%a in ("!line:;=|;!") do ( 
  set "line=%%a%%b%%c%%d%%f"

 echo !line:|=! 
)) > MOD.csv
```

OUTPUT 3 - `Don't give me anything`

I need advices please

Comment: `for /?` has all you need.

Comment: @Stephan   But how do I write the code?

Comment: read the output of `for /?` to learn what `tokens` and `delims` are. The rest should be easy enough. (this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+read+file+line) provides a lot of examples, which are easy to adapt to your use case. Please come back when you have some code that doesn't quite do what you want (and edit your question accordingly to have it re-opened) - currently your question is a mere code request and so off-topic for this site.

Comment: You want to remove the first two columns and keep the rest. The token `*` means "all the rest", so try `for /f "tokens=2,* delims=;" %%a in (original.csv) do echo %%b`, where `%%a` is the second column (not in output, but needed to make "the rest" valid) and `%%b` is "the rest".

Comment: your first code: `%%aa` isn't valid. `for`variables are one-letter only. `type` tries to type a file, you want `echo` instead. The approach would work, had you started with `%a` instead of `%w`. It would then be `echo %%a;.....;%%m`

Comment: Your second code: there are the parameter variables `%1` to `%9`. `%10` etc would be interpreted as `%1` plus a literal `0`, so this approach is doomed.

Comment: Your third code: if you replace  each `;` with `|` before trying to split by `;`, of course it won't work. And you try to output only five columns anyway.

Comment: @Stephan
with this code i'm geting the results

``
@echo off 
:main
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (ORIGINAL.csv) do (
call :sub1 %%a
)
goto :eof
:sub1
for /f "tokens=2,* delims=;" %%a in (ORIGINAL.csv) do echo %%b
) >> MOD.csv
goto :eof
``
But he is not writing automatically in the MOD.csv file

Comment: Code is hard to read in comments, but there seems to be imbalanced parentheses. Anyway: did `(for /f "tokens=2,* delims=;" %%a in (original.csv) do echo %%b)>mod.csv` work for you? (There is no need for a second `for` loop)

Comment: Nice
You're right, i don,t need the a second  ``for`` loop

But now the result is not being automatically written to the MOD.csv file

Comment: But you've helped me a lot, Thanks

Comment: works totally fine here with `original.csv` copy-pasted from your question. `mod.csv` contains exactly your desired output. (Btw: I needed to edit my previous comment due to a typo - maybe you tried the faulty code from before the edit - please try again)

Comment: I've tried the faulty code,

It runs very well, Thank you